# Replace Text in String

Tags: string, text, replace

I'm trying to write a RegEx expression to replace specific text in a string where parts of the text are variable.

For example, the text strings are the following:

```
XX                23080900012308091439
XX                23080900012308011439
XX                23080900012308231439
XX                23080900012308151439
```

For a text string that starts with **XX** and ends with **1439**, I want to replace 1439 with another 4-digit number (like 1234).

After the find-and-replace, the output would be:

```
XX                23080900012308091440
XX                23080900012308011440
XX                23080900012308231440
XX                23080900012308151440
```

Each time I try to write a RegEx to find the text, it's giving me all instances of "1439" (not just ones in a text string that starts with XX).

1. Is there a way to restrict the search to strings that start with XX and end with 1439?
2. Is there a way to only make the replacement if the string starts with XX?

Edited to add:

This is what has worked so far:

Find:    `^(XX\s+)(\d{16})(.*)$`

Replace: `$1$21440`

https://regex101.com/r/dD0E4t/1

I think I'm getting close, but I can't get a text editor to recognize the syntax.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Your regex is almost right - it should be `^(XX\s+)(\d{16})(1439)$` - but it's unclear how you're getting the results that you say you're getting.

Comment: You can match `^(XX\s+\d{16})1439$` and replace with `$11440` https://regexr.com/7h11v

Comment: Thanks for both solutions! My next newbie question is: how do I actually use the RegEx in a text editor? I've tried in both Notepad++ and TextPad, and it can't find the text using the expression. I can't figure out how to attach a screen shot of the the dialog box, but the error is `"Find: Can't find the text "^(XX\s+\d{16})1439$"`. Is there another way (or another program) that I should use to execute the search?

Comment: Many text editors and IDEs support regex. Commenting to the problem you're facing with Notepad++: Did you try to match a simpler expression? Start simple, and construct your regex piece by piece, by testing that your solution still matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Notepad++ (make sure you select **Regular expression**), you use a single capture group:

```
^(XX\s+\d{16})1439$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(XX\s+\d{16})` Capture group 1, match `XX` followed by 1+ whitespace chars and 16 digits
- `1439`
- `$` End of string

*(note that you can also use `\h+` instead of `\s+` to match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars)*

In the replacement use the value of capture group 1 followed by 1440 like `\11440`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H68IgA/1)

Or you can make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far, and use only `1440` in the replacement.

```
^XX\s+\d{16}\K1439$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqsycf/1)

[image]